# Gatsby cannot find directories/files in .cache

Tags: gatsby, contentful

I'm using the [gatsby-source-contentful plugin](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-source-contentful) with `downloadLocal` set to `true`:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-contentful",
  options: {
    spaceId: `my_space_id`,
    accessToken: `my_access_token`,
    downloadLocal: true,
  },
},
```

However, when I run `gatsby develop`, it looks like Gatsby cannot find the local files in .cache. I get these errors:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/basedir/.cache/caches/gatsby-transformer-sharp/diskstore-df6bcaa954c0509aba9763a79d7b38ae.lock'
>
> ERROR
>
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/basedir/.cache/caches/gatsby-transformer-sharp/diskstore-76c631915cff90316264f3f99de26b5c.lock'

And:

> WorkerError: Processing /basedir/.cache/gatsby-source-filesystem/02a25f085c33da92b05fb482655e7db3/FILENAME_HERE.jpg failed
>
> Original error:
>   /basedir/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor/cwebp: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

When I look into .cache/gatsby-source-filesystem and .cache/caches/gatsby-transformer-sharp, I see that the files do exist.

Here is my query in gatsby-node.js:

```
    allContentfulBlogPost {
      nodes {
        featuredImage {
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxWidth: 100) {
                src
                srcSet
                ...
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I've tried clearing .cache. I've put these into gatsby-config.js:

```
   {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `cache`,
        path: `${__dirname}/.cache`,
      },
    },
   {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `cache-gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
        path: `${__dirname}/.cache/caches/gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `cache-gatsby-source-filesystem`,
        path: `${__dirname}/.cache/gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      },
    },
```

I've also seen [this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16590) but I don't think it's exactly the same issue.

What should I do to make Gatsby find those files and directories in .cache?

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby keeps a cache of data and rendered assets in the .cache folder at the root of a Gatsby site so that it doesn’t have to repeat work processing optimized resources.

Try: `gatsby clean` and then `gatsby develop`.

Follow this [link](https://www.gatsbyjs.cn/docs/troubleshooting-common-errors/) for more info.